# moving figure to the right

Tags: graphics, floats, subfloats

I have a  landscape figure in my document that I want to move to the right because a small part of the figure falls of the page (there is enough space on the right to display it entirely without reducing the size)

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width = 0.4 \textwidth]{figures1}
 \end{figure}
\end{landscape}
```

Comment: Does either [Center figure that is wider than \textwidth](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16582) or [How to shift graphics/adjust placement of figure with \includegraphics](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107340) help?

Comment: the answers suggested for these questions don't work unfortunately

Comment: Not David Carlisle's answer on the second on either? (With a positive length in `\hspace*`, of course.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\begin{landscape}
\vspace*{1cm}
\hspace*{2cm}\includegraphics[width = 0.4 \linewidth]{figures1}\hspace*{-2cm}
\end{landscape}
```

why only .4 of the available width? In any case you can change the `1cm` and `2cm` to put the image anywhere on the page.