# Positioning includegraphics vertically on a line?

Tags: graphics, positioning

Lets' say I want to emulate an underlined signature; so I have this image:

[image: testing.png]

... which has been generated with the ImageMagick `convert` line included in this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% create testing.png using ImageMagick convert
% call w/ `pdflatex -shell-escape test.tex` to have the command run
% note: \includegraphics ignores the 150dpi set here, and will
% output bigger image than 2x0.6 in; *unless* -units pixelsperinch is set
% - but then it may give wrong resoltion in `identify -v`?...

\immediate\write18{convert -units pixelsperinch -density 150 -size 300x100 xc:white -draw "decorate UnderLine font Comic-Sans-MS-Regular font-size 30 fill dodgerblue text 20,70 ' Testing '" testing.png}

\begin{document}

Just testing something here... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,...

\noindent%
Attempt at signature: \makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace*{2cm}\vspace*{-2cm}\includegraphics{testing.png}}\hrulefill

That's all, folks ...
\end{document}
```

The document compiles to this:

[image: test.png]

I was basically trying to output the image first as a `\llap` (its `\mbox` construct [I guess] is taken from [\llap (or \rlap) at the beginning of an indented paragraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146098/llap-or-rlap-at-the-begining-of-an-indented-paragraph)), and then have the horizontal under-line via `\hrulefill` typeset over the image. That generally seems to work.

Then I was trying to position the image, so that its underline aligns with the `\hrulefill`. As [How to shift graphics/adjust placement of figure with \includegraphics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107340/how-to-shift-graphics-adjust-placement-of-figure-with-includegraphics) notes, `\hspace*` works here (`\hfil` unfortunately doesn't work, as the overlap `\mbox` apparently has to have width of 0pt) - and I'm pleased with the horizontal position.

The problem is the vertical position - how can I push the image "down", so its underline aligns with the `\hrulefill` one? Clearly `\vspace*` doesn't work (and using something like `\rule{0pt}{2cm}` moves all of the rows, while the relative vertical position between the image underline and the `\hrulefill` one does not change).

Comment: Did you try `\raisebox`?

Comment: Thanks @egreg - nope, forgot completely about it `:)` will try it now...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `\raisebox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

Just testing something here... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,...

\noindent
Attempt at signature:
\makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace*{2cm}\raisebox{-3ex}{\includegraphics{testing.png}}}%
\hrulefill

That's all, folks ...
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for that, @egreg - that does the trick! Cheers!