# How to move includegraphics

Tags: includegraphics

Exactly this question : 
[How to shift graphics/adjust placement of figure with \includegraphics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107340/how-to-shift-graphics-adjust-placement-of-figure-with-includegraphics)

but only half the answer is given, since using \hspace* works as intended, i.e. I can move my includegraphics wherever I want left or right. The problem is, using \vspace* in the same manner results in shifting the whole frame up and down, and not only my includegraphics.

So my question is : how to move includegraphics figures?

Comment: Please provide a minimum working example to show your problem.

Comment: There is always \raisebox.  It can adjust the baseline, height and depth independently.  For horizontal positioning, \rlap and \llap can prove useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possibility is to use the `tikz` package:

```
\documentclass[a4]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node [xshift=0cm,yshift=0cm] at (current page.center){\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

You can change the position with `[xshift=0cm,yshift=0cm]`