# Add extra space at the bottom with a rectangle containing an image, TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, tikz-styles

To draw a border around an image, I'm using rectangle from TikZ. Within the rectangle, I want to label the diagram. But the image is such that it occupies the rectangle's full space, so there is no space left to write the label. If I increase inner sep, it adds space in all 4 directions, which I don't want to happen. I want to add extra space at the bottom only. If I set a minimum height for the rectangle, then the image gets centered, and so there will be extra space at the top. I don't want this to happen either. I couldn't find an option to align the image to the bottom of the rectangle. Any help is appreciated.

PS: Currently, I'm adding an empty rectangle and then adding the image separately. Due to this, the inner sep for the rectangle will be zero. I've three similar diagrams, and I've to set inner sep for the other two rectangles also to zero. As a result, for the first diagram, a block within the diagram overlaps with the border rectangle.

```
% Contains figures for the presentation
%! Author = Nagabhushan

% Preamble
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

% Packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows, positioning, calc, decorations.pathreplacing, external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=figures/]
\newcommand{\etal}{\textit{et al.}}

% --------------------------- TikZ blocks - Start --------------------------------%
\tikzstyle{container} = [rectangle, rounded corners, draw=black, dashed]
\tikzstyle{circle-label} = [circle, text centered, draw=black]
% --------------------------- TikZ blocks - End --------------------------------%

% Document
\begin{document}
    \tikzsetnextfilename{Model_BlockDiagrams}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
        \node (main) [container, inner sep=0] at (current page.north) {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{../../images/MainArchitecture_BlockDiagram.pdf}};
        \node (mcs) [container, below of=main, yshift=-4.5cm, inner sep=0] {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{../../images/MCS_BlockDiagram.pdf}};
        \node (rfd) [container, below of=mcs, minimum height=4.5cm, minimum width=\linewidth, yshift=-4cm] {};
        \node (rf-image) [below of=rfd, yshift=2.5cm]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{../../images/RFD_BlockDiagram.pdf}};
        \node [circle-label, align=center, below of=main, right of=main, xshift=3.5cm] {A};
        \node [circle-label, align=center, below of=mcs, right of=mcs, xshift=3.5cm, yshift=-0.3cm] {B};
        \node [circle-label, align=center, below of=rfd, right of=rfd, xshift=3.5cm, yshift=0.3cm] {C};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \newpage
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

I made few changes to your MWE:

- instead obsolete `\tikzstyle` is now used `\tikzset`
- for container is used node, which by use of TikZ library `fit` encapsulate your image and image label
- first is insert image, then follows image labels in `circle-label` node, and on the end both are encapsulated in `container` using `fit` library
- for positioning of nodes are used relative coordinates as they are define in `positioning` library

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

% Packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usetikzlibrary{%external,
                fit,
                positioning}
%\tikzexternalize[prefix=figures/]
%\newcommand{\etal}{\textit{et al.}}

% --------------------------- TikZ blocks - Start --------------------------------%
\tikzset{
   container/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners, draw, dashed,
                       fit=#1, inner sep=2mm, node contents={}},
circle-label/.style = {circle, draw}
        }
% --------------------------- TikZ blocks - End --------------------------------%

% Document
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=4mm and 3mm]
\node (g1) [inner sep=0pt] {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{../../images/MainArchitecture_BlockDiagram.pdf}};
\node (cl-1)    [circle-label, below left=of g1.south east] {A};
\node (c1) [container=(g1) (cl-1)];

\node (g2) [inner sep=0pt, below=of c1] {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{../../images/MainArchitecture_BlockDiagram.pdf}};
\node (cl-2)    [circle-label, below left=of g2.south east] {B};
\node (c2) [container=(g2) (cl-2)];

\node (g3) [inner sep=0pt, below=of c2] {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{../../images/MainArchitecture_BlockDiagram.pdf}};
\node (cl-3)    [circle-label, below left=of g3.south east] {C};
\node (c3) [container=(g3) (cl-3)];
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \newpage
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked! However, my exact requirement is slightly different. For the first two diagrams, I don't want to put the lab below the figure. This is because for the first two diagrams there is some empty space at the bottom right. I'll place my label there. But for the third diagram, I want to add extra space. Can you tell me how I can modify your code to achieve this?

Comment: @NagabhushanSN, if I understand you correct, than at the first two image you need to delete `\node (cl-1)    [circle-label, below left=of g1.south east] {...}` and delete its name in `fit` option in ˙container` node, for example `\node (c1) [container=(g1) (cl-1)];`

Comment: I deleted passing `cl-1`, `cl-2` to `container` and added `yshift` to nodes `cl-1`, `cl-2` and it worked. Full code: `\node (g1) [inner sep=0pt] {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{../../images/MainArchitecture_BlockDiagram.pdf}};
        \node (cl-1)    [circle-label, below left=of g1.south east, yshift=1.2cm] {A};
        \node (c1) [container=(g1)];`

Comment: Thanks for this. Also can you elaborate on the usage of `\tikzset` instead of `\tikzstyle` or any links for the same?

Comment: @NagabhushanSN, `tikzstyle` is considered to be deprecated. See TikZ & PGF Manula`. It is part of your LaTeX installation, also you can find on Internet using Google :-)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/191575/178369), I modified my code as follows and it worked. The crux is that the extra space required can be added by using the `trim` option in `\includegraphics` and providing negative values for the bottom. Like `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, trim=0 -1cm 0 0]{../../images/RFD_BlockDiagram.pdf}`

**Modified code:**

```
% Contains figures for the presentation
%! Author = Nagabhushan

% Preamble
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

% Packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows, positioning, calc, decorations.pathreplacing, external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=figures/]
\newcommand{\etal}{\textit{et al.}}

% --------------------------- TikZ blocks - Start --------------------------------%
\tikzstyle{container} = [rectangle, rounded corners, draw=black, dashed]
\tikzstyle{circle-label} = [circle, text centered, draw=black]
% --------------------------- TikZ blocks - End --------------------------------%

% Document
\begin{document}
    \tikzsetnextfilename{Model_BlockDiagrams}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
        \node (main) [container] at (current page.north) {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{../../images/MainArchitecture_BlockDiagram.pdf}};
        \node (mcs) [container, below of=main, yshift=-4.5cm] {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{../../images/MCS_BlockDiagram.pdf}};
        \node (rfd) [container, below of=mcs, yshift=-3.65cm] {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, trim=0 -1cm 0 0]{../../images/RFD_BlockDiagram.pdf} };
        \node [circle-label, align=center, below of=main, right of=main, xshift=3.5cm] {A};
        \node [circle-label, align=center, below of=mcs, right of=mcs, xshift=3.5cm, yshift=-0.3cm] {B};
        \node [circle-label, align=center, below of=rfd, right of=rfd, xshift=3.9cm, yshift=0.4cm] {C};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \newpage
\end{document}
```

**Method2**:
Based on [Zarko's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/568180/178369), the below works too!

```
% Contains figures for the presentation
%! Author = Nagabhushan

% Preamble
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

% Packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows, positioning, calc, decorations.pathreplacing, external, fit}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=figures/]
\newcommand{\etal}{\textit{et al.}}

% --------------------------- TikZ blocks - Start --------------------------------%
\tikzset{
container/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners, draw, dashed, fit=#1, inner sep=2mm, node contents={}},
circle-label/.style = {circle, draw}
}
% --------------------------- TikZ blocks - End --------------------------------%

% Document
\begin{document}
    \tikzsetnextfilename{Model_BlockDiagrams}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=4mm and 3mm]
        \node (g1) [inner sep=0pt] {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{../../images/MainArchitecture_BlockDiagram.pdf}};
        \node (cl-1)    [circle-label, below left=of g1.south east, yshift=1.2cm] {A};
        \node (c1) [container=(g1)];

        \node (g2) [inner sep=0pt, below=of c1] {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{../../images/MCS_BlockDiagram.pdf}};
        \node (cl-2)    [circle-label, below left=of g2.south east, yshift=1.2cm] {B};
        \node (c2) [container=(g2)];

        \node (g3) [inner sep=0pt, below=of c2] {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{../../images/RFD_BlockDiagram.pdf}};
        \node (cl-3)    [circle-label, below left=of g3.south east] {C};
        \node (c3) [container=(g3) (cl-3)];
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \newpage
\end{document}
```